# how to edit link buttons in Bootbox / Bootstrap confirm window

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I have a simple bootbox / javascript confirm window at:

https://www.guard-gate.com/test2/index.html

How do i edit the links for Sucess to point to google.com?

I was advised the following:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

But would i have to add it to the code as follows?

```
  buttons: {
    success: {
  label: "Success!",
  className: "btn-success",
  callback: function(window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";) {
    Example.show("great success");
```

Comment: You need to use the code inside the function method. What you are currently doing is, passing it as a parameter to the function method. http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/xwL4csoh/

Answer (score 1):

Your code would be

```
buttons: {
    success: {
      label: "Success!",
      className: "btn-success",
      callback: function() {
         window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
      }
   };
```